# Excel VBA CustomSort from Range

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

```
Sub RRC()

Dim noOfLists As String
With Sheets("All_list")
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=Range("AU2:AU4")
noOfLists = Application.CustomListCount
noOfLists = noOfLists + 1

End With

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("All_list").ListObjects("All").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("All_list").ListObjects("All").Sort.SortFields.Add2 _
        Key:=Range("All[RRC]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
        CustomOrder:=CVar(noOfLists), DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("All_list").ListObjects("All").Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With


Application.DeleteCustomList (noOfLists - 1)


End Sub
```

Could anyone Help to figure out why this does not work, it runs, but does not sort.
Range AU2:AU4 will be dynamic, meaning that sorting there will always be different, therefore the key moment here is to use the latest sort in that range when applying VBA

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would have used. Let me know if there's a reason you're using the `CustomOrder` in the actual sort

```
Sub RRC()

  Dim currWorksheet As Worksheet
  Set currWorksheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("All_list")
  Dim newRangeSort As Range
  Dim newRangeKey As Range

  ' Fields to be sorted
  Set newRangeSort = currWorksheet.Range("AU2:AU4")
  ' "Header" column of which to sort from
  Set newRangeKey = currWorksheet.Range("AU1")

  'Your sort
  Dim customSort As String
  customSort = ("test")

  'Actual sort
  currWorksheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
  newRangeSort.Sort Key1:=newRangeKey, Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
      OrderCustom:=Application.CustomListCount + 1, MatchCase:=False, _
      Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

  ' clean up
  Set currWorksheet = Nothing

End Sub
```

There should be no reason to use a `With` here. This is a much better way of pulling a custom sort, as using vba - `Application.AddCustomList` is just an awful way to do things - very unfriendly

Comment: Thank you for a reply, just figured out what was wrong and used Jiont for CustomOrder

Comment: Awesome. I recommend adding your solution as an answer in case anyone else has the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i did, after some intzernet research:

```
    Sub Segment()

Dim x() As Variant

With Sheets("All_list")

.Range("AP2:AP10").Clear
.Range("AO2:AO10" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AO").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
.Range("AP2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False

x = Application.Transpose(Sheets("All_list").Range("AP2:AP10").Value)

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("All_list").ListObjects("All").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("All_list").ListObjects("All").Sort.SortFields.Add2 _
        Key:=Range("All[Segment]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
        CustomOrder:=Join(x, ","), DataOption:=xlSortNormal

End With

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("All_list").ListObjects("All").Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With


End Sub
```

First ranges just copy paste code cells into text, otherwise macro doe not run, join allowed to skip creation of custom list in excel